# Flink, multiple time windows?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We read data from kafka, the message could be simplified to a Tuple2, here String is the key, and Integer is the type (could be 1, 2, 3), something like,

```
('key001', 1)
('key001', 2)
('key001', 3)
('key001', 3)
('key002', 1)
('key002', 2)
('key003', 1)
('key004', 1)
```

We want to get some statistics info, for a 10 minutes window,

- count the keys which have type 1,
- count the keys which have both type 1 and type 2,
- count the keys which have all 3 types

I have tried below code, seems works, but look twisted to me, is this correct way to go?

I have to use time window twice here, since using one time window doesn't give what I want, I'm still not clear about the way it works, can anyone explain what happens when apply multiple time windows to the stream?

```
SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple2<String, Long>> x = ds.keyBy(0)
        .timeWindow(Time.seconds(600))
        .process(new ProcessWindowFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Tuple2<String, Long>, Tuple, TimeWindow>() {

            @Override
            public void process(Tuple key,
                    ProcessWindowFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Tuple2<String, Long>, Tuple, TimeWindow>.Context ctx,
                    Iterable<Tuple2<String, Integer>> elements, Collector<Tuple2<String, Long>> out) throws Exception {

                boolean hasType1 = false;
                boolean hasType2 = false;
                boolean hasType3 = false;
                for (Tuple2<String, Integer> t2 : elements) {
                    if (t2.f1 == 1) {
                        if (!hasType1) {
                            hasType1 = true;
                        }
                    } else if (t2.f1 == 2) {
                        if (!hasType2) {
                            hasType2 = true;
                        }
                    } else if (t2.f1 == 3) {
                        if (!hasType3) {
                            hasType3 = true;
                        }
                    }
                    //
                    if (hasType1 && hasType2 && hasType3) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (hasType1) {
                    out.collect(new Tuple2<>("hasType1",1L));
                    if (hasType2) {
                        out.collect(new Tuple2<>("hasType1_Type2",1L));
                        if (hasType3) {
                            out.collect(new Tuple2<>("hasType1_Type2_Type3",1L));
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        });

x.keyBy(0).timeWindow(Time.seconds(600)).sum(1).map(new MapFunction<Tuple2<String, Long>, String>(){

    @Override
    public String map(Tuple2<String, Long> value) throws Exception {
        return value.f0 + " = " + value.f1;
    }

}).addSink(new BucketingSink<String>("hdfs://...")).setParallelism(1);
```

Comment: Are these event time, or processing time, windows?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Hi David, it's processing time.